# GitHub organization is not appearing in Continous Deployment page

Tags: azure, github, continuous-deployment

My personal GitHub account is part of five organizations. When setting up Azure's continuous integration from GitHub, only four of the five organizations appear in the list.

We have tried logging in and out of both GitHub and Azure. Also, we have tried changing the account in Azure and then re-adding the same account. Still it does not appear.

How do we make the organization appear in the Azure Continuous Deployment page? Do we need to set specific permissions in GitHub? I am already a member of the target organization and an admin of the target repository.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the organization's Third-party access to No restrictions.

[image: No Restriction]

Comment: Awesome... saved the day. Thanks

Comment: I don't recommec this setting since it's a potential security vurnerability. See my answer.

Comment: @SzymonSeliga your answer won't work for me because the Azure GitHub Actions application is not listed.

Comment: Are you using GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 7):

In your profile go to `Settings -> Applications`. Now select the `Authorized OAuth Apps` tab

[image]

Now click on `Azure Github Action` and grant access to the missing organizations.

[image]

Comment: What is the process for getting "Azure GitHub Actions" added to that list?

Comment: Whilst setting up the pipeline in Azure DevOps, who have to option to select GitHub as the source of you repository. You then have to authenticate with GH and is the Azure GitHub Actions isn't setup yet, you will be asked to grant access for it.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it wasn't called "Azure App Service" rather than "Azure GitHub Actions"