# Continues deployment not working properly with github private repository

Tags: azure, github, continuous-deployment, azure-git-deployment

Azure continues deployment not working properly with github private repository. I am using Azure deploy button method.

**Error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)**

README.MD

```
<a href="https://azuredeploy.net/?repos...{repoURL}" target="_blank"><img src="http://azuredeploy.net/deployb..."/></a>
```

azuredeploy-parameters.json

```
"repoUrl":{
"value":"{repourl}.git"
}
```

azuredeploy.json

```
"repoURL": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "{repoUrl}.git"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Github responds with a 404 error when you try to access a repository that's not public and you're not allowed to access it.
Make sure that the github user you're using from Azure to connect to Github has access to the Github repository.
When using an SSH key to connect to Github, make sure the SSH key is linked to a user that has access to the repository.

In case that's already configured correctly, at a look at this question: [GitHub organization is not appearing in Continous Deployment page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439127/github-organization-is-not-appearing-in-continous-deployment-page)